# Is there any share option in Google Maps API V2 for android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have developed an app, in which Im using map option to display the user stores in google map using Google map API V2 for it.
I'm able to display the map with 2-3 market in it, every this is working fine.

I want to share that map with marker and all to pc as a url.So that i can open in browser.

How can i do it?

Is it possible to do it or not ?

Comment: i want to share that map view to browser as an url.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they offer functions to do it. But you can build your own, which looks something [like this](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=googleplex&z=20):

`http://maps.google.com/maps?q=[ADDRESS]&z=[ZOOMLEVEL]`

you can always refer to the [Google Maps Embed API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide) for more information.

*note that, sadly, there are no way for adding multiple markers into the `maps.google.com`.